# Getting the cursor to the other window in a split vim

Tags: vim, vi

I wonder how I can get my cursor to the other window in the right side?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd>, then use <kbd>l</kbd>(el) or left arrow → .
This will take you to right windows. You can use any navigation keys like `hjkl` accordingly to go to `left`, `below`, `above` and `right` respectively or the arrow keys.

If <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> will go one by one from view to view